# How to create a sublist from 2 lists by selecting their items index wise

Tags: python, list, concatenation, addition

I have a `list1=[1,2,3,3,4]` and another `list2=[2,4,5,6,7]`.
I want to produce `list3=[[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[3,6],[4,7]]`

```
n=int(input())
ls=[]
ls1=[]
ls2=[]
ls3=[]
ls=list(map(int,input().split()))
ls1=list(map(int,input().split()))
for i in ls:
    for j in ls1:
        if i==j
            a=ls.index(i)
            b=ls1.index(j)
            ls2.apppend(a)
            ls3.append(b)
ls4=[i,j for i,j in zip(ls2,ls3)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
list3 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list3.append([list1[i], list2[i]])
```

Or, the list comprehensive version of the above code as

```
list4 = [[list1[i], list2[i]] for i in range(len(list1))]
```

Both will output

```
[[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `zip` method and apply a *list comprehension* over it.

```
pairs = [list(pair) for pair in zip(a,b)]
```

Use `list` constructor because `zip` method returns *tuples*.